# Can i run a website on Amazon S3 ? Say, by using Amazon S3 PHP SDK?

Tags: amazon-s3

What exactly the SDK can be used for ? Only for storage like it's done on google drive, box or dropbox etc ? Or can i use the stored scripts to run a complete website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly the SDK can be used for?

The [Software Development Kit (SDK)](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp) can be used to programmatically control nearly every single aspect across all [40± AWS services](http://aws.amazon.com/products/).

> Only for storage like it's done on google drive, box or dropbox etc?

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is a storage-only service. It complements the plethora of other AWS services.

> Or can i use the stored scripts to run a complete website?

For that, you'd need something with a server. I recommend taking a look at [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) first because that's arguably the quickest way to get something running. If you're looking for something with more control, you can check out [AWS OpsWorks](http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/).

If you want a raw virtual server, take a look at [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). If you want to build a template that can automate and configure nearly your entire cloud infrastructure (storage, compute, databases, etc.), take a look at [Amazon CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/).